# Capistrano / Git error when increasing the number of servers

Tags: git, capistrano, capistrano3

I use Capistrano to deploy my Rails app in production. Everything works fine with about 10 servers. However if I add more servers (e.g. 5) I start getting errors from Capistrano:

```
Command: export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.2.2" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/example/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads example@repo.example.com:repo/example.git

cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as example@app4.example.com: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The additional servers are just clones, so they have the correct access rights. The repository exists and works fine with less servers. Moreover, when I add new servers, the same failure sometimes occurs on a new server but sometimes occurs on an old server. So the failure doesn't occur on the same server: if I run the Capistrano deploy multiple times, I get the same failure, but always from a different server.

Maybe the problem is on the server that hosts the git repository. Maybe it can't handle so many concurrent ssh connections - why? Has anyone experienced this problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with the max number of ssh connections allowed by the server which hosts the git repository.

On Ubuntu I've edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and now everything works! Add or adjust the following values:

```
MaxSessions 50
MaxStartups 40:30:50
```

See sshd_config for more details.